# What is the quickest way to check invalid login attempts in Symfony2 FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle in Symfony2 to handle user registration and authentication. I want **lock out user accounts after three invalid login attempts**. So, what is **quickest way to check invalid login attempts** in Symfony2 FOSUserBundle?

***Solution so far***

Maybe I have to define `$attempts` attribute on `User` object to identify the invalid login attempts count. Then I can use a `AuthenticationHandler` class to handle login attempt ( using onAuthenticationSuccess() and onAuthenticationFailure() )

Comment: [CCDNUserSecurityBundle](https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNUserSecurityBundle) achieves this. you can view the source or just include it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, CCDNUserSecurityBundle is great bundle to work with. But the problem I have is I am already using FOSUserBundle as the base bundle for my UserBundle, so I am looking for a solution which uses Symfony2 or FOSUserBundle

Comment: that bundle works with [any User Bundle](https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNUserSecurityBundle#you-can-use-this-bundle-with-any-user-bundle-you-like)

Comment: yes, but already using FOSUserBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle in my UserBundle so I can't inherit multiple user bundles

Comment: You don't neet to. As @CarrieKendall pointed out all you need is the right setting in your `config.yml`. See the [example configuration](https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNUserSecurityBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md) for help.

Comment: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/03/symfony2-security-enhancements-part-ii/ might also help here - it gives an example of using an event listener and a [UserChecker](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserChecker.php) subclass to achieve this.